# Sum Of Array Table

Tags: c++

I was able to print a list of array in a 2D table with the code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void inputRoutine( vector<int> &a )
{
   const int MAXNUM = 17;
   for ( int i = 1; i <= MAXNUM; i++ ) a.push_back( i );
}


void printRoutine( vector<int> a )
{
   const int COLS = 5;
   int size = a.size();                                         
   int fullrows = size / COLS;                                 
   int leftover = size % COLS;                                  
   int rows = fullrows + ( leftover != 0 );                    

   cout << "TABLE:\n";
   for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )                            
   {
      int indexTop = 0;                                         
      for ( int j = 0; j < COLS; j++ )
      {
         int index = indexTop + i;                              
         if ( i < fullrows || j < leftover ) cout << a[index];  
         cout << '\t';                                          
         if ( j < leftover ) indexTop += rows;                  top-of-column 1-d index for the number in this column
         else                indexTop += fullrows;              
      }
      cout << '\n';
   }
}


int main()
{
   vector<int> a;
   inputRoutine( a );
   printRoutine( a );
}
```

and i was able to produce the output as the below

```
TABLE:  1  5  9  12  15
        2  6  10 13  16
        3  7  11 14  17
        4  8
```

Now i want to get the Sums of the printed table as below
(The First Numbers Are The Column Numbers, first line with the column number 5 indicate the individual row sums 42, 47, 52, 12 as in the table given. the second line with the column number 1 : if there is only 1 column then there are 17 rows - it should produce the total of numbers)

```
C   ROW SUMS

5   42 47 52 12
************************************
1   153
************************t***********
2   11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 9
************************************
```

How to do this part, could some one help.

Comment: 42 = 1+5+9+12+15            52=3+7+11+14+17
47 = 2+6+10+13+16          12=4+8

Comment: Should it run through all possible options for `COLS` or only a finite set, e.g., `1 < COLS < 6`?

Comment: It when Col 5 is selected The Sums of Each Row Should Be calculated and When Column 1 is Selected the sum of 1 to 17 should be calculated

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it, would be to have a buffer `row_sum` which is this case is populated (and calculated) when printing the table.
After the table is printed then `row_sum` contains the calculated row sums. You could chaneg `COLs` to be a parameter of `printRoutine` such that it is possible to run through different values of `COLS` without recompiling.

[Here](http://ideone.com/58z0hw) is a simple extension of your original code, that runs for `COLS = 1,...,5`. For each value of `COLS` it prints the table and the row sums.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

void inputRoutine( vector<int> &a )
{
   const int MAXNUM = 17;
   for ( int i = 1; i <= MAXNUM; i++ ) a.push_back( i );
}

void printRoutine(int COLS, vector<int> a, vector<int>& row_sum)
{
   int size = a.size();                                         
   int fullrows = size / COLS;                                 
   int leftover = size % COLS;                                  
   int rows = fullrows + ( leftover != 0 );                    

   // Set the size of the row_sum buffer
   row_sum.resize(rows);

   cout << "TABLE:\n";
   for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )                            
   {
      int indexTop = 0;                                         
      for ( int j = 0; j < COLS; j++ )
      {
         int index = indexTop + i;                              
         if ( i < fullrows || j < leftover )
         {
            cout << a[index];

            // Add the value to the row sum. We do the add here, since
            // if it should be printed it should also be added
            row_sum[i] += a[index];
         }
         cout << '\t';                                          
         if ( j < leftover ) indexTop += rows; // top-of-column 1-d index for the number in this column
         else                indexTop += fullrows;              
      }
      cout << '\n';
   }

   // Special case for COLS == 1
   if (COLS == 1)
   {
      row_sum[0] = std::accumulate(std::begin(row_sum), std::end(row_sum), 0);
      row_sum.resize(1);
   }
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> a;
   inputRoutine( a );

   for (int COLS = 1; COLS < 6; ++COLS) // Here we loop over a few selected value of COLS
   {
      vector<int> row_sum; // To store the row sums
      printRoutine( COLS, a, row_sum );

      // The rest of the loop is just printing the row sums
      std::cout << '\n' << COLS << '\t';
      for (int i : row_sum)
         std::cout << i << ' ';
      std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Jonas According to your code it shows 5 separate tables for the Sum, but my requirement it to get the sums of columns 5,1,2 in one table seperated by stars not in separate tables

Comment: @Eranka If you only want those values for `COLS` then just change the for loop: `for (int COLS = 1; COLS < 6; ++COLS)`

Comment: @Eranka If you don't want to print the table just comment it.

Comment: Out put has to show the 2D table and the Sum Table, What change has to be done to get it on one table as my example separated by stars rather than getting it under the 2D table.